# Git - removing a commit

Tags: git, github, revert

I forked a repo on Github a few months ago, and have made three commits. I'd like to submit a pull request with some bug fixes back to the original project, but one of the commits had some changes which don't apply to them.

How on earth do I fix this? I'm coming from an svn background, so most of the terminology, etc. has a very different meaning that I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch with only the changes you want, and submit a pull request from that instead of your master.  Doing `git branch origin my-new-branch-name` will create a new branch you can work on without any changes from your work.  Then `git checkout my-new-branch-name` will start work on it.  Then apply your changes with e.g. `git cherry-pick my_commit_id_1 my_commit_id_1`.  Finally `git push ssh://remote.host/path/to/repo my-new-branch-name` will push it to the server from which you can issue a pull request.

Comment: That actually clears a lot of things up re: workflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To just get rid of the commit, you can do the following.

- Run `git log` to get the hash of the commit that you want to get rid of
- Run `git rebase --interactive abc123^`, where abc123 is the hash of the bad commit
- Delete the bad commit from the list that pops up in your editor (delete the line with that commit: leave the other lines)
- Save and close the editor, and Git will rebase all later commits onto the parent of the bad commit

Comment: +1 I'm sure this'll work, but I gave up after 20 pages of logs. It's a pretty active project.